# Word Find/Replace Add Tab at the Beginning of Paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I'd like to add a tab before each line of my Word document. Each line is a paragraph anyway so this may be easy to do.

More, some lines have a digit or two and would be nice to have an extra tab after the number.

Example:

from this:

```
1 text text...
text text...
```

to this:

```
1->Text text...
 ->Text text...

45->Text text...
  ->Text text...
```

The numbers are typed in. Not a list.

Also the numbered lines is not needed to have a tab before. Only the lines starting with text.This is because the text should be correctly alligned, one line after the other.

Here is the screenshot of Find/Replace window. I had to use my local characters (polytonic Greek) for this.

After many tries it worked finally.
[image: Find/Replace]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . So you're looking to do 2 (or 3) things? First adding a tab "before" each paragraph start, then adding a tab between the number at the beginning of the paragraph and the text after that, and then another tab in the middle of the paragraph (as in *1->Text text... **->** Text text...*, but based on what is that? Since it's still in one line?)

Comment: I see now the real intent (it wasn't formatted here correctly so it looked like one line.) Are this numbers a numbered list or simply a typed number?

Comment: The way to format text to show as preformatted (like code) is by adding 4 spaces in the line before the text, or select the text and press the angle brackets icon in the question editing toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing it with two steps as follows:

First, to add a space at the beginning of all paragraphs starting with letters (not digits) ***Find what*** (with *Use wildcards* ticked):

```
(^13)([A-Za-z])
```

Replace with:

```
\1^t\2
```

Then to add the tab after the numbers in the paragraphs that start with a number ***Find***:

```
(^13[0-9]@)( )
```

And **Replace with**:

```
\1^t
```

I think this should work well for you. Note one thing, it will not replace the first line at of the document (since it relies on the paragraph mark of the line before to know the beginning of a paragraph.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. On my side only the first step works as expected.
The second step replaces all numbers with tab. On your example it keeps the number.

All these symbols are explained somewhere so that I can use them in the future please?

Comment: You can read [this guide](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm), and I can also try to edit my answer and explain those specific ones I used, but first let's get it to work for you. Please click on "Show/Hide Non-Printing Characters" ([see here](https://www.teachucomp.com/show-non-printing-characters-in-word-instructions/) and capture a screenshot of how it shows your text. Edit your question and add the screenshot

Comment: Thank you very much for the info on find/replace and support.